# Can we get the count of created nodes of a specific document type in Umbraco razor view

Tags: razor, umbraco, umbraco8

If i have a node with documenttype alias as "entry", which is created as a child node to many different root and child pages, is there a way to get the total count on created "entry" type nodes and display in razor view in Umbraco?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, of course, for v7 use:

```
Model.Content.Site().Descendants("entry").Count()
```

for v8

```
@Model.Root().DescendantsOfType("entry").Count()
```

Comment: Davor thanks for the response but this seems to have changed or is missing in Umbraco 8

Comment: @SabRa you are right, I added a version for umbraco v8